# How to apply security updates for Microsoft .NET core (August 2023) to update Microsoft.netcore.app from 6.0.2 to 6.0.21

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-sdk

I have "Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview" - 17.2.0 Preview 1.0 version installed. The server also has "Microsoft .NET SDK 6.0.200 (x64) from Visual Studio" installed in control panel.
The Tenable has reported a security vulnerability "Apply Security Update for Microsoft .NET Core (August 2023)” to update "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.2" from the current '6.0.2' to '6.0.21' version.
To fix this vulnerability, can I attempt to update the "Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview" from the current '17.2.0 Preview 1.0' to latest '17.8.0 Preview 1.0'. Please confirm if it would take care of updating "Microsoft .NET SDK 6.0.200 (x64) from Visual Studio" to latest version (August 2023)? And also update 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App' to '6.0.21' version?

On one of my previous attempt, when I installed standalone SDK 6.0.301 (Windows x64 version) using 6.0.6 version in https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0, this created two '.NET SDK' versions in control panel. One with old 'Microsoft .NET SDK 6.0.200(x64) from Visual Studio' and second with 'Microsoft .NET SDK 6.0.301 (x64)'. This is not what I want, since it also creates two Microsoft.NETCore.App versions 6.0.2 and 6.0.6. The requirement is to update 6.0.2 (old) version to latest and not show both old and new versions separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the test result, the answer looks like yes. We are able to update the SDK installed when installing VS via updating the VS.

before:

[image]

after:

[image]